# Can we update same rows in two tables in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to update a row in two tables in Postgresql?

The table names are `patron` and `cir_transaction`

The column name is `patron_id`

I need to update the same rows of `patron_id` which is present in both above tables

I wrote like below

```
update patron p, cir_transaction c 
set patron_id = '4BW14MBA10' 
where patron_id = '4BW14MBA10 ' and c.patron_id = patron_id
```

Comment: No, you need to run two `update` statements.

Comment: Updating primary key value is a bad design sign. Otherwise (if `patron_id` isn't PK) just run two update-s in one transaction and voilà.

Comment: You should start a transaction, acquire locks on both rows (or tables) first, and then update the rows. Otherwise you might run into a deadlock situation.